# Run Windows Java program in Ubuntu 12.04 without Wine

Tags: windows, wine, java

If a Windows program (*.msi) was written in Java, is there a way for me to extract the contents and install it taking advantage of Java's cross-platform capabilities? I'd like to install it bypassing Wine.

Comment: There are Linux tools that can extract MSI archives in some cases, namely `7z` from p7zip and `msiextract` from [msitools](//wiki.gnome.org/msitools). Otherwise I recommend to look for whatever you want to set up in a different archive format. It may be easier to build the application from source. Maybe people can help you, if you tell them what program you're talking about.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I'm looking into those tools right now. The program is a very small program I need for work, here's the link: http://bit.ly/1z6twlm

Comment: Contact them for linux support. http://www.translated.net/en/contact-us  Let them know youre willing to pay, and expect platform support.

Comment: I would install the actual program in windows or mac (a supported system) then try to work with the files directly

Answer (score 2):

1. Install `msitools` - it is needed to use `msiextract`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install msitools
   ```
2. Extract the [MSI file](http://bit.ly/1z6twlm)

   ```
   msiextract TAV.msi
   ```
3. Go into `Program Files/TAV`

   ```
   cd "Program Files/TAV"
   ```
4. Extract the EXE file

   ```
   unzip TAV.exe
   ```
5. Check the `MANIFEST.MF`

   ```
   Manifest-Version: 1.0
   Class-Path: .:./org/hyperic/sigar/natives/
   Created-By: 1.5.0_22 (Oracle Corporation)
   Main-Class: tav.TAV
   ```

   Your main class is `tav.TAV`
6. Start the main class

   ```
   java tav/TAV
   ```

   and your app is running, without WINE **;)**

   [image]

Comment: :D :D :D  Good one!

Comment: Don't thank me. **;)** Accept the answer with a click on the check mark at the left side of the answer. Means, the answer is valid.